# Mocking a class that contains lambda expressions with PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, lambda, powermock

I'm trying to mock a class which contains lambda expressions in a method, -as in the example below - and it fails in the initialization:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {}

public class MyClass {   

    public void letsSeeLambda() {
        this.forTesting((a, b) -> true);
    }

    private void forTesting(Filter filter) {
        filter.process(5, 6);
    }
}
```

the error that appears is the following:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name .....MyClass. 
>   Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
>       at ...

I'm using powermock 1.6.3, junit 4.12, mockito 1.10.19

If I do it in a new project it works, obviously. The problem occurs only in the existing project I'm working on.

What's my problem?

Comment: I don't see any mocks. Did I miss something? Lambdas are just syntactic sugar for one method classes so you can definitely mock them but not if you can't supply them as a parameter.

Comment: The error is in the initialization. It means it doesn't arrive to see even the test methods.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.
The order of the dependencies in the pom wasn't correct.

It turns out that the order matters.

The javassist dependency must appeear after the powermock dependencies.

Comment: It would be good to accept this answer and tell us which items in the pom were out of order so anyone stuck on the same issue can learn.